# How to return the value taken off of an array by using .shift()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab the value from `arr.shift()` that I am taking out of the array and I need to return that value, how would I go about doing this?

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  arr.push(item);
  arr.shift(); 

  return arr; // Change this line
}

// Test Setup
var testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Display Code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

Comment: `return arr.shift()` to do it in one line. With your current code, you'd need to store the result of `.shift()` in a variable, then return the variable

Comment: What do you mean by _return that value_? Return it from the function or return it to the array?

Answer (score 3):

Just return `arr.shift();`

**Example:**

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
    arr.push(item);
    return arr.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value to a variable

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  arr.push(item);
  var tmp = arr.shift(); 

  return tmp;
}
```

or alternatively

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  arr.push(item); 

  return arr.shift();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, array shift removes the first element of an array and also returns the same. So, as mentioned in previous answers, "return arr.shift()" would be returning the element that is removed from array.

Note: shift() is similar to the pop() function of array. The only difference is that pop removes the element with the last index(length of array-1) of the array whereas shift removes the element with first index(0). But, pop and shift return the element that is removed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was not creating the variables.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Only change code below this line
 
  let addThis = arr.push(item);
  let removeThis = arr.shift();

  return removeThis;
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Setup
let testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Display code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```